# ggarrange not showing axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, cowplot

I have made 4 circular boxplots with `ggplot2` and they look ok individually (although ideally, I would like the x-axis names further outside of the plot).

[image: One circular boxplot]
But when I use `ggarrange` from the `ggpubr` package to make a multi-panel plot my axis names are partially missing.

[image: ggarranged circular boxplots]

With the following code:

```
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2, font.label = list(size = 25))
```

I have also tried `Gridextra` and `cowplot` but I get the same issue.

Any help anyone can give would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Annalise

Comment: You could try with package 'patchwork'. We cannot give any more detailed answer unless you provide a reprex (self contained code and data minimal example that demostrates the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text labels on the x axis of polar plots can be problematic. You might want to try `coord_curvedpolar` from the geomtextpath package, which allows the labels to curve around the plot, helping to prevent clashes and clipping. Additionally the labels can eadily be moved radially outwards or inwards using `vjust`

Obviously, I don't have your data, but here's a mock-up:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Season = c("Winter\n2019", "Summer\n2019", "Autumn\n2019", 
                            "Winter\n2020", "Summer\n2020", "Autumn\n2020"),
                 Index = c(54.5, 55.5, 55, 56.4, 53.6, 55.5))

col_list <- list(c("#d14719", "#ffd175"), 
                 c("#751975", "#ffa3d1"),
                 c("#146f6f", "#75ffff"),
                 c("#751919", "#fe1818"))

p <- lapply(col_list, function(x) {
  ggplot(df, aes(factor(Season, Season), Index, fill = Index)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_minimal(base_family = "Roboto Condensed", base_size = 12) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1:6, linetype = 2) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Index - 5, ymax = Index + 5), width = 0.5) +
    geomtextpath::coord_curvedpolar() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = x[1], high = x[2]) +
    labs(fill = "Average Total Carlson State Index") +
    guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"),
          legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "mm"),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", vjust = 0.5))
})

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = p)
```

[image]